# JQuery Mobile Panel Widget – opening collapsible lists causes jump scroll to bottom of page div once expanded beyond page height. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Trying to build a collapsible, multi-level menu using JQuery Mobile's (v 1.4.5) Panel widget. I've added some slideUp/Down animation to make the opening of the submenus more apparent.

```
<div data-role="page">

<div data-role="panel" id="mainmenu" role="navigation" data-display="overlay">
  <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview-outer">
    <li><a href="#">Home Page</a></li>
    <li data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
      <h3>LIST 1 OF 6</h3>
      <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b">
        <li><a href="#">1.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">1.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">1.3</a></li>
        <!-- etc. -->
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
      <h3>List 2 OF 6</h3>
      <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c">
        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">2.1</a></li>
        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">2.2</a></li>
        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">2.3</a></li>
        <!-- etc. -->
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
      <h3>List 3 OF 6</h3>
      <ul data-role="listview">
        <li><a href="#">3.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3.3</a></li>
        <!-- etc. -->
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
      <h3>LIST 4 OF 6</h3>
      <ul data-role="listview">
        <li><a href="#">4.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4.3</a></li>
        <!-- etc. -->
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
      <h3>LIST 5 of 6</h3>
      <ul data-role="listview">
        <li><a href="#">5.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5.3</a></li>
        <!-- etc. -->
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
      <h3>LIST 6 OF 6</h3>
      <ul data-role="listview">
        <li><a href="#">6.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">6.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">6.3</a></li>
        <!-- etc. -->
      </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div data-role="header" class="header">
<a href="#mainmenu" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a><h1>This is the header
</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content" class="content">
This is the content
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<!-- <br>'s etc. to increase page length for illustrative purposes -->
</div>

<div data-role="footer" class="footer">
This is the footer
</div>

</div>
```

Issue: When the height of the menu exceeds the height of the page div (which happens quickly as the topmost submenu is quite long), and then *another* submenu further down is expanded/collapsed, the viewport jumps such that the bottom of the page is at the bottom of the viewport, pushing the freshly opened submenu below the viewport, and doubtlessly confusing the user as to what just happened.

Ideally the submenu that was just clicked stays in view, the slideDown animation is visible and the user understands the the submenu has opened. JQuery seems to be dynamically changing the page height based on the menu height, which makes sense, but the sudden shift of the viewport... less so.

The behavior persists with or without the slide animation, included below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(document).on("collapsibleexpand", ".ui-collapsible", function (event) {
        var contentDiv = $(this).children(".ui-collapsible-content");
        contentDiv.hide();
        contentDiv.slideDown(300);
        event.stopPropagation(); // don't bubble up
    });

    $(document).on("collapsiblecollapse", ".ui-collapsible", function (event) {
        var contentDiv = $(this).children('.ui-collapsible-content');
        contentDiv.slideUp(300);
        event.stopPropagation(); // don't bubble up
    });
});
```

[Working fiddle to show the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/halfacre/sn7s4224/2/)

I'm far from being a JQuery/JS/JQM expert, and there may well be something I'm doing here that is not recommended (e.g., I've not seen much about nesting lists in a panel for navigation). If so, I'm open to hearing about it.

Comment: I believe You will need two scrollbars, one for the panel and one for the page content, then set the panel scrollTop()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my proposal for such a kind of navigation system. IMHO there shall be two scrollable elements, the page content and the menu subsystem (side panel).

I can't fully understand Your sentence "*... the viewport jumps such that the bottom of the page is at the bottom of the viewport*"  but anyway, I like Your idea of a sliding sub-menu, so i believe the difficulty here is: how to calculate the amount of scrolling needed to move the current menu item to the top.

Please, be aware that I haven't tested this piece of code in all circumstances, but at first glance, it seems to be ok - at least in the browser.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("collapsibleexpand", ".ui-collapsible", function(e) {
    var self = $(this), 
        menu = $("#mainmenu"),
        pageY = $(document).scrollTop(),
        content = $(this).children(".ui-collapsible-content");
    content.hide();
    content.slideDown({
        duration: 300,
        step: function(now, fx) {
          if (fx.prop == "height") {
            var pct = ((100 * now) / fx.end),
              itemTop = $(self).offset().top,
              menuScrollTop = $(menu).scrollTop(),
              amt = (itemTop - pageY) / 100 * pct;
            menu.scrollTop(menuScrollTop + amt);
          }
        }
      }
    );
    e.stopPropagation(); // don't bubble up
  });

  $(document).on("collapsiblecollapse", ".ui-collapsible", function(e) {
    var content = $(this).children('.ui-collapsible-content');
    content.slideUp(300);
    e.stopPropagation(); // don't bubble up
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  text-align: center;
}

#mainmenu {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
}

.ui-page-active {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  min-height: 100% !important;
}

li,
ul {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="panel" id="mainmenu" role="navigation" data-display="overlay">
      <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview-outer">
        <li><a href="#">Home Page</a></li>
        <li data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
          <h3>LIST 1 OF 6</h3>
          <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b">
            <li><a href="#">1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.9</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.10</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.11</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.12</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.13</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.14</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.15</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.16</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.17</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.18</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.19</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.20</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.21</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.22</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.23</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.24</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.25</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.26</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.27</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.28</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.29</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
          <h3>List 2 OF 6</h3>
          <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c">
            <li><a href="#">2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2.4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2.5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2.6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2.7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2.8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2.9</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2.10</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2.11</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2.12</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2.13</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2.14</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2.15</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2.16</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
          <h3>List 3 OF 6</h3>
          <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="#">3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3.4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3.5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3.6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3.7</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
          <h3>LIST 4 OF 6</h3>
          <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="#">4.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4.3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
          <h3>LIST 5 of 6</h3>
          <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="#">5.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">5.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">5.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">5.4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">5.5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">5.6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">5.7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">5.8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">5.9</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">5.10</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
          <h3>LIST 6 OF 6</h3>
          <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="#">6.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">6.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">6.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">6.4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">6.5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">6.6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">6.7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">6.8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">6.9</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">6.10</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="header" class="header">
      <a href="#mainmenu" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>
      <h1>This is the header</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" class="content">
      This is the content
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" class="footer">
      <h1>This is the footer</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Kindly, test this approach above on all Your available devices and give me a feedback.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll give it a shot and let you know! Yeah, I had a hard time formulating a description of that viewport change – or even just figuring out what exactly was happening at first. Essentially, if you open more than one submenu at once, such that the height of the menus became longer than the data-role="page" div, opening any further submenus would result in the view "jump-scrolling" (lacking any better term for the sudden change), positioning the footer at the bottom of the browser viewport (in Chrome and Safari), making one lose one's bearings. The darnedest thing...

Comment: This, my friend, works flawlessly on every real and virtual device I've tried. Simple, elegant and absolutely lovely... the two scrollbar solution is definitely the way to go. I particularly like how the chosen submenu repositions itself at the top of the viewport – UI gold, and solves a host of issues. Brought it into the actual project and it's freaking awesome. A+. Many, many thanks.